# Recargar página pasando parámetro Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

He estado investigando como poder recargar una página en `Javascript` modificando la `URL` que toma al momento de hacerlo, pero estoy confundido.

Por ejemplo, yo tengo mi `URL` original  `http://localhost:8503/Inicio.aspx` y la modifico a `http://localhost:8503/OVIRTUAL` mediante :

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'OVIRTUAL');
```

Pero entonces cuando refresco la página me manda un error ya que el URL que obtiene para recargar la página es el modificado.

En el siguiente código lo que hago es obtener primero el original y después reescribir la `URL`. Ahora lo que quiero es que haga la función es que cuando se apriete la tecla `F5` o el refrescar mande la original y así pueda refrescar mediante la `URL` guardada en `URLactual`.

```
var URLactual = window.parent.location.href;

    function recargarPage(URLactual) {


          if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 116) {
            window.location.assign(URLactual);
        }
    }
    window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'OVIRTUAL');
```

Investigué que usando los eventos de teclado de javascript pero también que se podría con `location.reload` pero la verdad estoy un poco confundido, alguien podría guiarme? Hice esa función pero no me funciona.

Comment: Deja ver si entendí... lo que necesitas es que por medio de la URL se recargue la página y al momento de recargar la página te muestre un parámetro en la URL? ejemplo: "http://localhost:8503/Inicio.aspx?OVIRTUAL"

Comment: No no no xD La URL modificada es la de http://localhost:8503/OVIRTUAL, y mi original http://localhost:8503/Inicio.aspx. Cuando refresco la página me manda un error porque el URL que usa para refrescar es el modificado. Entonces capturo el original en URLactual y quisiera que al refrescar de cualquier forma utilice ese URL no el modificado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude lograrlo :v no sé si a alguien le sirva pero esto fue lo que hice:

```
var URLactual = '';

$(document).ready(function () {

if (URLactual == '') {

    URLactual = window.parent.location.href;
}

window.history.replaceState({}, '', 'OVIRTUAL');


$(document.body).on("keydown", this, function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {
        window.location.assign(URLactual);
    }
});
});
```